# How to reference collection's data in render() when fetched in initialize() in BackboneJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I'm trying to get my head around the correct way to organise a view when it's calling multiple collections (some which only need to be fetched initially and some which are triggered by events).

I have a collection 'Genres_collection()' which fetches a list of genres from a database:

Genres_collection:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/genre_model'
],function($,_,Backbone,Genre_model){
    var Genres_collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Genre_model,
        url: '/api/genres',
        parse: function(response){
          return response;
        }
    })
    return Genres_collection;
});
```

Genres_model:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
],function($,_,Backbone){
    var Genre_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            'title': 'Untitled Track'
        }
    })
    return Genre_model;
});
```

I have a view which, amoung other things, I want to fetch the genres on initialize() and then reference the collection's data in render. From my understanding, initialize is triggered only when a view is initialted (thus the name) and render() is called any number of times (ie: when an event is triggered). So, my thought is that render is used to render and 're-render' a view when actions are taken.

Therefore, I have the following view code:

Search_view:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/tracks',
    'collections/genres',
    'text!templates/search_view_title.html',
    'text!templates/search_view.html'
],function($,_,Backbone,Tracks_collection,Genres_collection,Search_view_title_template,Search_view_template){
    var Search_view = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#app'),
        
        initialize: function(){
            this.collection = new Tracks_collection();
            this.genre_collection = new Genres_collection();
            this.genre_collection.fetch();
        },
        search: function(searchtype){
            switch(searchtype){
                case 'genre':
                    console.log('genre changed');
                    this.collection.fetch({
                        data: {limit: 30, type:'genre',genre_id:$('#genre_select').val()}
                    });
                break;
                case 'search':
                    console.log('search changed');
                    this.collection.fetch({
                        data: {limit: 30, type:'search',keyword:$('#keyword').val()}
                    });
                break;
            }
        },
        render: function(){
            // MAKE 'THIS' ACCESSIBLE
            var that = this;

            
            console.log(this.genre_collection);

            var template = _.template(Search_view_template);
            var template_vars = {genres: this.genre_collection};
            console.log(template_vars);
            var template_html = template(template_vars);
            that.$el.find('#container').html(template_html);
            


            this.collection.bind('add',function(collection){
                console.log('collection has been changed');
            })
                      
        }
    });

    return Search_view;

});
```

However, when I try to print the genre_collection in render() to the console or pass it to the template, I don't get the data from the collection which was fetched in initialize().

1. Is this the correct way to organising this type of call?
2. Where is it going wrong? How can I get it to pass the data from this.genre_collection in render()?

I am using requirejs and I can confirm that the initialize() and render() call is being called as I have written simpler views which execute the code fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your `this = that` you should write

```
console.log(that.genre_collection)
```

instead of

```
console.log(this.genre_collection);
```

Add this to your initialize function

```
this.listenTo(this.genre_collection , 'change', this.render);
```

you can change your  genre_collection parse nmethod so it will return your data

```
parse: function(response){
    return response.genres
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference whatsoever. This and that are the same and thus this.genre_collection = that.genre_collection

Comment: nope, just an object. If I assign the .fetch() to a variable, I get another object which had the data stored in it as responseText and responseJSON, but I don't know the correct way to access it.

Comment: Sorry, that's not made a difference either. I understand what you are trying to do there, but I don't think it's the solution. I simply can't reference the response from this.genre_collection.fetch() to pass into a template within render()

Comment: I initially had that, but because I intend on update this.collection, I didn't want to trigger the this.genre_collection.fetch() each time render is called.  I thought it would be a good idea to make the initial collection fetch in itialize() as it only needs to be done once. If I bind any change to this.collection to render() then it's goign to re-fetch, but I suppose I could just use a different view 'method' to deal with that.

Comment: It's an excellent idea (it's a right way) that's why this.listenTo(this.genre_collection , 'reset', this.render); should work for you just add it before fetch.

Comment: and your render should return this add it

Comment: @David plz add this listner  to your initialize  funtion this.listenTo(this.genre_collection , 'reset', this.render);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126655/discussion-between-david-and-v-s-v).